# Wordpress: Hide categories from add new post page

Tags: wordpress

I would like to forbid the contributors from adding categories to posts. What I found out was this function `remove_post_type_support()`. However in the documentation it doesn't talk about tags or categories. I tried `remove_post_type_support( 'post', 'category' );` and `remove_post_type_support( 'post', 'categories' );` but neither worked.

Is there a way of doing so?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this, it is **untested** but I think it would work.

Simply deregister the taxonomy from the post type: register_taxonomy is used for both creation and modification.

Put it in your function.php file

```
if ( current_user_can('contributor') )

 function contributors_unregister_categories() {
    register_taxonomy( 'category', array() );
 }
 add_action( 'init', 'contributors_unregister_categories' );

}
```

Comment: sweet, glad I could help :-)